# take screenshot with imagemagick in openbox via shortcut (rc.xml) on Linux

Tags: terminal, imagemagick, sh, screenshot, openbox

I need to take screenshots and save them adding timestamp in filename.

The following command in terminal is working well:

```
import -window root -quality 100 screenshot_$(date +'%Y_%m_%d_%R_%S').jpg
```

I've inserted this in the .config/openbox/rc.xml

```
<keybind key="A-Print">
<action name="Execute">
<command>import -window root -quality 100 screenshot_"`date +%Y%m%d%R%S`".jpg
</command>
</action>
</keybind>
```

Then by Terminal:

```
openbox --restart
```

Now, If I click on PrtScn button Imagemagick takes a screenshot but saves it with *+%Y_%m_0_%R_%S).jpg* filename.

I've also tried to create a script file coping that command in a file script-screenshot-imagemagick.sh, I made it executable with *chmod +x*, I inserted this code in rc.xml:

```
<keybind key="A-Print">
<action name="Execute">
<command>/home/ste/Programmi-Installati/script-screenshot-imagemagick/script-screenshot-imagemagick.sh
</command>
</action>
</keybind>
```

but after restarting Openbox, if I click on PrtScn button Imagemagick takes a screenshot saving it with *+%Y_%m_0_%R_%S).jpg* filename again!

What is wrong?
Perhaps the plus character is somehow disturbing...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Openbox does not do shell expansions](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions). You need to pass your command directly to shell:

```
<command>bash -c 'import -window root -quality 100 screenshot_"`date +%Y%m%d%R%S`".jpg'</command>
```